# Translate sld:name and ogc:property name into GeoServer CSS

Tags: sld, geoserver-css-module

Given is following SLD rule:

```
<sld:Rule>
  <sld:Name>mytrack#</sld:Name>
  <ogc:Filter>
    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      <ogc:PropertyName>jogging</ogc:PropertyName>
      <ogc:Literal>always#</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
  </ogc:Filter>
  <sld:MinScaleDenominator>100</sld:MinScaleDenominator>
  <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>1000</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
  <sld:LineSymbolizer>
    <sld:Geometry>
      <ogc:PropertyName>alltracks</ogc:PropertyName>
    </sld:Geometry>
    <sld:Stroke>
      <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#ff0000</sld:CssParameter>
      <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</sld:CssParameter>
    </sld:Stroke>
  </sld:LineSymbolizer>
</sld:Rule>
```

which I would write with css like:

```
[jogging='always#'][@scale>100][@scale<1000] {
  stroke: #FF0000;
  stroke-width: 1;
}
```

and what is translated by geoserver into following sld:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0">
  <sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Rule>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>jogging</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>always#</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:MinScaleDenominator>100.0</sld:MinScaleDenominator>
          <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>1000.0</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <sld:LineSymbolizer>
            <sld:Stroke>
              <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#0029FF</sld:CssParameter>
              <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">1.5</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Stroke>
          </sld:LineSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:VendorOption name="ruleEvaluation">first</sld:VendorOption>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

**How can rename**

```
<sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
```

**to**

```
<sld:Name>mytrack#</sld:Name>
```

Comment: Good question. I couldnt figure it out as well. Changing the name within the SLD breaks the CSS workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently a patch of mine was integrated into GeoTools 15 (I think) to solve this issue for **title** and **abstract** (style name is on the way).

https://github.com/geotools/geotools/pull/1017

It uses the not well known possibility of CSS directives within a CSS style.

```
@styleTitle "myStyleTitle is here";
@styleAbstract "myStyleAbstract is here";
```

so your style would be:

```
@styleTitle "mytrack#";

[jogging='always#'][@scale>100][@scale<1000] {
  stroke: #FF0000;
  stroke-width: 1;
}
```

Maybe the possibility of setting the style title is enough for you.

**Edit**:
At the moment I am not sure setting style name is needed.

Comment: It's thus available as part of the 2.9.x series (dev branch) nightly builds here: http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/master/

Comment: Thx Andrea. Wasn't sure about Geoserver target version.